# Morphia/MongoDB: Accessing "embedding" object from an @Embedded object

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a Morphia schema similar to this one:

```
@Entity
class BlogEntry {
    @Embedded
    List<BlogComment> comments
}

@Embedded
class BlogComment {
    String content
    Long authorId
}
```

(code above just for illustration)

I'm trying to get a specific BlogComment in order to update it with new content. I have the corresponding BlogEntry object available, and I have the authorId, which let's say for the purposes of this question that these two together are sufficient to uniquely identify the correct BlogComment.

My question is, BlogComment does not explicitly contain a reference to its "parent" BlogEntry object, so how can I write a morphia query to retrieve this BlogComment? Something like:

```
//fetch the unique comment corresponding to this blog entry and this author ID.
BlogComment comment = ds.find(BlogComment.class, "blogEntryId =", blogEntry.id)
                        .filter("authorId", authorId)
                        .get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have the blog entry object why not use a simple Java loop to filter it out?

```
@Entity
class BlogEntry {

    @Embedded
    List<BlogComment> comments

    public BlogComment findCommentByAuthorId(String authorId) {
        if (null == authorId) return null;
        for (BlogComment comment: blogEntry.comments) {
           if (authorId.equals(comment.authorId) return comment;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I considered looping through the BlogComments but that seemed like it would be slow. Another possibility I've considered is to add a field "blogEntryId" to BlogComment that contains the id of the parent object. This might be faster, but it doesn't seem right to be explicitly storing the ID of the embedding object inside each embedded object. Is there no implicit handle to the parent?

Comment: looping through the list is an operation in memory, should be much much faster than you get anything out from database, coz the latter involves inter-process-communication, disk IO (might be waived because of cache) etc. Another thing is you cannot let morphia query to return an embedded object only

Comment: Ah okay, good call on in-memory vs db access. Yeah, it does seem like Morphia queries even using the "dot notation" will only return the parent objects and not the embedded objects. Using a loop seems to be the way to go, thanks for your help!