# In Morphia how can i update one embedded Object inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Really new to Using Mongodb with Morphia and see many advanced answers how to do this.

I want to do it simple if it's possible and I have this `@Embedded` Object called
`fileObjects` that contains `Files` Objects.

I Cannot update the fields inside the `Files`.

I want to update only one field f.ex the `String fileHash`.

```
@Entity
public class BatchData {

    @Id private ObjectId id;
    @Embedded
    public ArrayList<Files> fileObjects = new ArrayList<Files>();
}
```

*UPDATE..*
Reading the wiki at [Morphia Updating](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating) dont "really" say how to do this only when the array contains `Integer` like this:

```
  @Embedded
   List<Integer> roomNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Here is what i try so far:

```
mongo.createUpdateOperations(BatchData.class).add("fileObjects", Files, false);
```

The `Files` that this code insert is already in the mongo. The `false` don't detect that and insert it at the end of the array. Can i add an unique-id to the `Files` so it detect that the `Files` am inserting exist in the array, and then just update it?

```
@Embedded 
public class Files
{ 
    public Files() {

    }

    public int position;
    public String fileName = "";
    public String fileHash = "";

    public Files(int pos, String fileName, String fileHash) {
        this.position = pos;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileHash = fileHash;
    }
}
```

Reading other answers like [morphia-mongodb-accessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884813/morphia-mongodb-accessing-embedding-object-from-an-embedded-object) but he already have the
@Entity BlogEntry(see link) in a POJO outside of mongo. Maybe i have to do the same?
Pull it out, change it and save it back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question for anyone's delight.

I think i solved it not sure.
It looks like it's working im testing when the `fileObjects` have many `Files`.
The right `fileHash` is updated indeed.

```
UpdateOperations<BatchData>updateOperations=mongo.createUpdateOperations
             (BatchData.class)
            .disableValidation().set("fileObjects.$.fileHash",hash).enableVali..;

mongo.update(mongo.createQuery(BatchData.class)
            .filter("uuid",theBatch.uuid)
            .filter("fileObjects.fileName","theFileName"),updateOperations);
```

Comment: It works very well. Morphia should support it natively. Now we must disable validation for using this "$" operator.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was able to use the removeAll method:

```
UpdateOperations<MyType> ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(
            MyType.class).removeAll("myEmbeddedList", "thevalue");
ds.update(ds.find(MyType.class).get(), ops);
```

This assume that MyType has the field List myEmbeddedList; and that there is a vlue "thevalue" to be removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I just (yeah, right now) solved this problem, in this way:
I get the root class with a query

```
List<Applications> fileList = mDatastore.createQuery(File.class).field("_id").equal(new ObjectId(ID)).asList();
```

Then, I have implemented the CRUD operations inside this root class (I'll post my root class):

```
@Entity
public class Applications extends BaseEntity{


    private String name;    
    private String owner;   
    private String version;

    @Embedded
    List<Resources> resources = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    List<Activities> activities = new ArrayList<>();

    @Embedded
    List<Components> components = new ArrayList<>();

    public Applications() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public Applications setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
        return this;
    }

    public List<Resources> getResources() {
        return resources;
    }

    public Applications setResources(List<Resources> resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
        return this;
    }

    public Resources getResourcesByName(String name) {
        for(Resources resource : this.resources){
            if (resource.getName().equals(name))
                return resource;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean containsResourceByName(String name) {
        for(Resources resource : this.resources){
            if (resource.getName().equals(name))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public Applications addResource(Resources newResource) {
        if (!containsResourceByName(newResource.getName())) {
          this.resources.add(newResource);
        }
        return this;
      }

    public Applications removeResource(Resources newResource) {
        if (containsResourceByName(newResource.getName())) {
          this.resources.remove(getResourcesByName(newResource.getName()));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Applications removeResourceByName(String name) {
        if (containsResourceByName(name)) {
          this.resources.remove(getResourcesByName(name));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public List<Activities> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

    public Applications setActivities(List<Activities> activities) {
        this.activities = activities;
        return this;
    }

    public Activities getActivityByName(String name) {
        for(Activities activity : this.activities){
            if (activity.getName().equals(name))
                return activity;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean containsActivityByName(String name) {
        for(Activities activity : this.activities){
            if (activity.getName().equals(name))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Applications addActivity(Activities newActivity) {
        if (!containsActivityByName(newActivity.getName())) {
          this.activities.add(newActivity);
        }
        return this;
      }

    public Applications removeActivity(Activities newActivity) {
        if (containsActivityByName(newActivity.getName())) {
          this.activities.remove(getActivityByName(newActivity.getName()));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Applications removeActivityByName(String name) {
        if (containsActivityByName(name)) {
          this.activities.remove(getActivityByName(name));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public List<Components> getComponents() {
        return components;
    }

    public Applications setComponents(List<Components> components) {
        this.components = components;
        return this;
    }

    public Components getComponentByName(String name) {
        for(Components component : this.components){
            if (component.getName().equals(name))
                return component;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean containsComponentByName(String name) {
        for(Components component : this.components){
            if (component.getName().equals(name))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Applications addComponent(Components newComponent) {
        if (!containsComponentByName(newComponent.getName())) {
          this.components.add(newComponent);
        }
        return this;
      }

    public Applications removeComponent(Components newComponent) {
        if (containsComponentByName(newComponent.getName())) {
          this.components.remove(getComponentByName(newComponent.getName()));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Applications removeComponentByName(String name) {
        if (containsComponentByName(name)) {
          this.components.remove(getComponentByName(name));
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Applications updateComponentByName(String name, String newName) {
        if (containsComponentByName(name)) {
          getComponentByName(name).setName(newName);
        }
        return this;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put(DatabaseModel.ApplicationsModel.FIELD_ID, id);
            jsonObject.put(DatabaseModel.ApplicationsModel.FIELD_NAME, name);
            jsonObject.put(DatabaseModel.ApplicationsModel.FIELD_OWNER, owner);
            jsonObject.put(DatabaseModel.ApplicationsModel.FIELD_VERSION, version);
            jsonObject.put(DatabaseModel.ActivitiesModel.DOCUMENT_NAME, activities);
            jsonObject.put(DatabaseModel.ResourcesModel.DOCUMENT_NAME, resources);
            jsonObject.put(DatabaseModel.ComponentsModel.DOCUMENT_NAME, components);
            return jsonObject.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Something went wrong";
        }

    }
```

Once, I modified my Application data I just save it to mongodb in the main program with:

```
mDatastore.save(mApplications);
```

Hope this can help you, bye!