# How to remove a specific element from ArrayList in morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I am using inherited `@Embedded` reference of ArrayList in Morphia `Entity` class.

```
@Entity
public class First {
  @Embedded private List<Second> secondClass;
  private String title;
  private Long id;
  ...  getter and setter .. methods
}

@Embedded
public class Second {
  @Embedded private List<Third> thirdClass;
  private String titleSecond;
  ...  getter and setter .. methods
}

@Embedded
public class Third {
  private String titleThird;
  private String logoUrl
  ...  getter and setter .. methods
}
```

## Json

```
{
  "secondClass": [{
    "thirdClass": [{
      "titleThird": "Java",
      "logoUrl": "http://www.artsfon.com/pic/201510//artsfon.com-72885.jpg",
    }, {
      "titleThird": "ios",
      "logoUrl": "http://www.artsfon.com/pic//1920x1080/artsfon.com-72885.jpg",
    }],
    "titleSecond": "Developer"
  }],
  "title": "Software Developer",
  "id" : 1234567890
}
```

## Questions

1) How to remove the element with the given value of `titleSecond` and `id`?

2) How to remove the element with the given value of `titleThird` and `id`?

For first I tried the following implementation:

```
UpdateOperations<First> ops;
Query<First> updateQuery = datastore.createQuery(First.class).filter("id", Long.parseLong(id.trim()));

ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(First.class).disableValidation().removeAll("secondClass.titleSecond", "Developer");
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

but it's throwing mapping error:

```
Write failed with error code 16837 and error message 'cannot use the part (secondClass of secondClass.titleSecond) to traverse the element.
```

How can I perform the action for question 1 and 2? Any help would be appreciable.

possibly linked question: [In Morphia how can i update one embedded Object inside an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203141/in-morphia-how-can-i-update-one-embedded-object-inside-an-arraylist)

Comment: Just curious how did you create this docs in the first place ? were you able to push the records into third class ? Separate question. How is second class tied to third class ? Can you move the third class as same level as second class ?

Comment: *Just curious how did you create this docs in the first place* I am passing the above `JSON` object and saving with `datastore.save(firstObject)`.  *were you able to push the records into third class * : Yes, I can see the records in `MongoDB`. *How is second class tied to third class * : I used `@Embedded private List<Third> thirdClass;` in `Second Class`. Please check out the posted JSON (` "thirdClass": [{...}]`).  *Can you move the third class as same level as second class * Actually, I cannot :(. Please do let me know If I have cleared your all questions?

Comment: actually its not about saving for the first time. My question was what if you want to add a new entry in the third class in the existing object ? Is that something you have tried ?

Comment: Not yet, I have to. would it not be a similar case if I run update the existing in `secondClass ` ? Let me try to implement your solution first.

Comment: okay. I think its not the  same. Atleast I was not able to get around that while trying to remove the entry in the third class. I will let you try pushing into third class. I haven't tried that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created records like this.

```
db.myCollection.insertMany([{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58609ed483ce6037ec33fc8c"),
        "secondClass" : [
                {
                        "thirdClass" : [
                                {
                                        "titleThird" : "Java",
                                        "logoUrl" : "http://www.artsfon.com/pic"
                                },
                                {
                                        "titleThird" : "ios",
                                        "logoUrl" : "http://www.artsfon.com/pic"
                                }
                        ],
                        "titleSecond" : "Developer"
                }
        ],
        "title" : "Software Developer"
}])
```

My First class. Rest of the classes are same.

```
@Entity("myCollection")
public class First {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String title;
    @Embedded
    private List<Second> secondClass;
```

Answer to the first part.

```
UpdateOperations<First> ops;
Query<First> updateQuery = datastore.createQuery(First.class).field("_id").equal(new ObjectId("58609ed483ce6037ec33fc8c"));

Second second = new Second();
second.setTitleSecond("Developer");
ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(First.class).disableValidation().removeAll("secondClass", second);
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

Alternate solution for first part.

```
UpdateOperations<First> ops;
Query<First> updateQuery = datastore.createQuery(First.class).field("_id").equal(new ObjectId("58609ed483ce6037ec33fc8c"));

ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(First.class).disableValidation().removeAll("secondClass", new BasicDBObject("titleSecond", "Developer"));
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

Answer to the second part.

```
UpdateOperations<First> ops;
Query<First> updateQuery = datastore.createQuery(First.class).field("_id").equal(new ObjectId("58609ed483ce6037ec33fc8c")).field("secondClass.thirdClass.titleThird").equal("ios");

ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(First.class).disableValidation().removeAll("secondClass.$.thirdClass", new BasicDBObject("titleThird", "ios"));
datastore.update(updateQuery, ops);
```

Comment: I tried but nothing had happened. Got successful response with no exception. I checked database but the entry was there. Do you want me to find the `TitleSecond`, fetch it and pass it to `removeAll("secondClass", second` ? or I just need to copy your code?

Comment: Added the complete code. It will help you understand better. Added the second part of the answer too. I'm using Morphia 1.3.0

Comment: Thanks sagar, "Alternate solution for first part" and "Answer to second part" titles work for me. :)